# How can library() accept both quoted and unquoted strings

Tags: r

For example, in an R session, typing `library(ggplot2)` and `library("ggplot2")` can both import the library ggplot2. However, if I type ggplot2 in the interactive session, I got:

```
> ggplot2
Error: object 'ggplot2' not found
```

Thus, obviously ggplot2 is not an object. How can library() accepts an undefined variable without complaining about it?

Comment: Because of a poor design decision. I know you are asking _how_ and not _why_. If you want to know how, read the first part of this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: And technically when you call `library(ggplot)` the parameter would be a "name" object rather than an unquoted string.

Comment: @MrFlick not exactly - the parameter is an unevaluated expression that would be an error if evaluated. `substitute(package)` is a name though.

Comment: @hadley I guess I was just going by `class(parse(text="library(ggplot2)")[[1]][[2]])` so perhaps it would be better to call it an evaluated name, but it should still be a name. I guess I wanted to clarify what "unquoted strings" really were.

Comment: What's the parameter of this function call? `x <- 1:10; f(x)`. I don't think it's reasonable to call it a name - it's a numeric vector. (Also rather than parsing a string, just use quote: `quote(library(ggplot2))`)

Comment: Well, in the case of `library` wouldn't you agree that the only acceptable values are names or character values? I can't think of another type of expression that would make any sense. I would agree that it's more reasonable to call `x` a numeric vector in the case of `f(x)` although technically it too is an "unevaluated expression" as is any parameter to any function -- we really have no idea what `f()` will do with that value. So if that's the point you are trying to make, I understand and agree.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I wouldn't call it a poor decision: at least for me, when software makes my life easier (don't need to remember whether or not to include quotation marks), I am happy:-) . So I would agree with MrFlick's response.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft IMO it is a poor decision, especially so because it is inconsistent. There are a bunch of functions that take package names, do you remember without checking the manual which ones need the quotes: `require`, `unloadNamespace`, `install.packages`, `packageVersion`, etc.? It is true that `library` is probably used most often, but I would still prefer if it was consistent.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I actually forgot `help()` for which there is no `character_only` argument, but you need to escape a variable using parens, e.g. `help((topic), (package))`. This of course does not work for `library()`. :-/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Great question!

Let's crack open the `library()` function to see how it works.

enter `library` into your interactive session to see the innards of the function.

The key parts of the function are from lines 186 to 197.

```
 if (!missing(package)) {
     if (is.null(lib.loc))
         lib.loc <- .libPaths()
     lib.loc <- lib.loc[file.info(lib.loc)$isdir %in% TRUE]
     if (!character.only)
         package <- as.character(substitute(package))
     if (length(package) != 1L)
         stop("'package' must be of length 1")
     if (is.na(package) || (package == ""))
         stop("invalid package name")
     pkgname <- paste("package", package, sep = ":")
     newpackage <- is.na(match(pkgname, search()))
```

The key lines are

```
if (!character.only)
             package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

This means that as long as you don't change the `character.only` argument of library to `TRUE`, R will convert your package name into a character string and search for that.

Let's test:

```
 > library(ggplot2,character.only=TRUE)
```

outputs:

```
 Error in library(ggplot2, character.only = TRUE) :
   object 'ggplot2' not found
```

whereas

```
library("ggplot2",character.only=TRUE)
```

loads the package.

Basically, no matter what you give the `library()` function as an argument for `package` it will convert it into a characters **unless** you specify character.only to be `TRUE`.

As Dason points out in the comments, a good use of the `character.only` argument is in cases where you have the library names stored as objects themselves.

Comment: With the true usefulness of `character.only` being when you're passing in a character string stored in an object.  For example `packagetoload <- "ggplot2"; library(packagetoload, character.only = TRUE)`

Answer (score 5):

This is how (from the source of `library()`, which is....long):

```
package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

A simple way to test this yourself:

```
foo <- function(x) as.character(substitute(x))
> foo(a)
[1] "a"
> foo("b")
[1] "b"
```