# Can't return a value from dataframe based on parameter

Tags: r, function, lookup

I apologize if this is an extremely straight forward or repeated question but I just can't seem to get or find the correct solution.

I am just trying to return a rate from a function based on input. So if my data frame is:

```
   January   0.02
  February   0.04
     March   0.06
     April   0.08
       May   0.10
      June   0.12
      July   0.14
    August   0.16
 September   0.18
   October   0.20
  November   0.22
  December   0.24
```

I am trying to return the growth based on input. So calling `monthly_growth(August)` should return 0.16.

I apologize if this is a fundamental issue and very straight forward but I can't seem to get it to pull - thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking at your function, if you have a data frame that looks like this, you will do `data.frame["August"]` to access the value with name "August"

Comment: @TomNash the OP will probably need `data.frame["August", ]`, assuming "August" is a row name (And the data.frame only has one column). Omitting the comma will throw an incorrect number of dimensions/undefined columns error.

Comment: You should read `?Extract` -- it sounds like you're having basic subsetting issues. To do the non-standard evaluation, i.e. `monthly_growth(August)` with no quotation marks around 'August,' take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25210455/1623354).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and references - having a read through them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example program:

```
mon <- c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
rate <- c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.18,0.20,0.22,0.24)

#create the dataframe to use for lookups
df <- data.frame(mon,rate)

#custom function - returns the rate for the month passed in.  No error checking
monthly_growth <- function(theMonth){
  return(df[df$mon==theMonth,"rate"])
}

#example usage
monthly_growth("August")
monthly_growth("October")
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you could use `df <- data.frame(mon = month.name, rate = seq(0.02, 0.24, 0.02))` to save yourself some key strokes.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you're only using month as an input to switch to a rate, you could use the `switch` function:

```
getRate <- function(month) {
  switch(month,
         January = 0.02,
         February = 0.04,
         March = 0.06,
         April = 0.08,
         May = 0.1,
         June = 0.12,
         July = 0.14,
         August = 0.16,
         September = 0.18,
         October = 0.2,
         November = 0.22,
         December = 0.24,
         "Invalid month.")
}

getRate("August")
# [1] 0.16
getRate("hello")
# [1] "Invalid month."
```

Just an FYI, with a little futzing you can make the function work for any capitalization of different "month" values and any capitalization of the month abbreviations, with or without quotation marks:

```
getRate2 <- function(month) {
  month <- tolower(as.character(substitute(month)))
  month <- paste0(toupper(substr(month, 1, 1)), 
                  substr(month, 2, nchar(month)))
  if (month %in% month.abb) month <- month.name[match(month, month.abb)]
  getRate(month)
}    

getRate2(AUG)
# [1] 0.16
getRate2(Aug)
# [1] 0.16
getRate2(AugUST)
# [1] 0.16
getRate2("aug")
# [1] 0.16
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I was hesitant to post this question but am pleased to have another tool now as a result.

Comment: @Hatt_haggerty Take a look at the edit. Kind of fun to make the function flexible.